# iText: Setting Custom properties as Metadata in PDF using Xmp

Tags: pdf, itext

I am creating a PDF file using iText 5.4.0. I need to add few custom properties to the pdf. 
I have tried two approaches

1. addHeader method of `com.itextpdf.text.Document` class and
2. setMoreInfo method of `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfStamper`.

But both of these add the custom properties to the info dictionary.

I need to add them using Xmp and retrieve back into an Xml File. How can I do this??

Comment: As explained with hand and feet on the iText mailing-list: you can only create an XMP stream from the info dictionary for the metadata described in PDF/A. There is no spec for mapping 'custom' data from the info dictionary to XMP for the simple reason that the data is 'custom'. You need to create the XMP stream using a custom XmpSchema that is developed by you the way it meets your custom requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes..!!.. got the custom schema implemented like this

```
public class CustomSchema extends XmpSchema 
{

private static final long serialVersionUID = -4551741356974797330L;

public static final String LABELID = "ls:LabelId";

public CustomSchema() {
    super("cusprop");
}

public void addLabelId(String labelId) {
    XmpArray array = new XmpArray(XmpArray.UNORDERED);
    array.add(labelId);
    setProperty(LABELID, array);
}
public void addLabelArr(String tagId, String[] tagValue) {
    XmpArray array = new XmpArray(XmpArray.ORDERED);
    for (int i = 0; i < tagValue.length; i++) {
        array.add(tagValue[i]);
    }
    setProperty(tagId.toString().replace(" ", "").trim(), array);
}
}
```

The resulting XML as below

```
     <rdf:Description rdf:about="" xmlns:ls="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
     <TagId-20>
        <rdf:Seq>
            <rdf:li>arr0</rdf:li>
             <rdf:li>arr1</rdf:li>
        </rdf:Seq>
     </TagId-20>
     </rdf:Description>
```

I want to know, if this structure also can be custom.
For example,

```
    -<TagId-20>
            -<customTag>
                    <ls:userId>USERNAME</ ls:userId >
                    <ls:WONum>12-110992</ WONum >
            </customTag >
    </TagId-20>
```

For getting the above structure, what I need to do?? Is there any example available?